# Pros and cons of two types of PivotTables for BI purposes

Tags: excel, user-interface, pivot-table

I am trying to figure out how to create the most useful PivotTable for a user to view data for BI purposes. Here are two options I was considerating:

(1) Traditional PivotTable, pivot values on top:

[image]

(2) Drill-down type PivotTable:

[image]

What are the pros and cons of each method? For example, one for each to start might be:

- Drilldown

  - PRO: trivial to add additional drilldown variables.
- Pivot:

  - PRO: can easily sort by the column headers in the table UI.

And, are there any other possible tabular displays of data, either another type of PivotTable or another type altogether?

Comment: One thing that I think about PivotTables and any other BI Report is: Do something easy for the User. I have already seen lot's of reports so complex that the user give up, and keep using his excel sheet. I think this is one important point to be check.

Comment: David do you have any update on what you're looking for here? You haven't given a lot of feedback on a question that, really, is too broad and opinion based to be asked here in the first place. Clarification and a narrower set of instructions on the deliverable qualities you're looking to achieve could help make this on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivot Tables are used to -

1. summarize data
2. analyze data
3. explore data
4. present summary data

Both ways (traditional and drill down) of Pivot table can do the above listed.

### It depends on what you want to achieve in BI.

If detailed data is not required to show or sort then you can use drill down.

Mostly in BI, data used in summarised form. So Drill down method will be good for display of data. Anyways you can double click and see the detailed data. See how to [get details of drill](http://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-drilldown.html)

**Drill Down:**

a. Pros

1. Summarise Easily
2. Add sub points for summary
3. "Get Details" of Pivot for more details

b. Cons

1. The way you are doing sorting by pivot is not possible. Instead I would suggest to use [pivot to drill down](http://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-drilldown.html). So you can sort (And will move to Pros section :P) and check pivot details in another form.

**Traditional Way**

This way you are making to use pivot tables of your data. You should explore more in given links below.

1. [5 pivot tables you probably haven't seen before](https://exceljet.net/blog/5-pivot-tables-you-probably-havent-seen-before)
2. [pivot tables save your job](https://exceljet.net/blog/can-pivot-tables-save-your-job)
3. [23 things you should know about Excel pivot tables](https://exceljet.net/things-to-know-about-excel-pivot-tables)

Comment: You note that drilling down is good for the display of data - but in a reviewed document, doesn't needing to drill down imply that the presentation is too limited initially? Also, both your pros and cons are recommending the drilldown method - so it's just a list of pros.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon: The way OP, suggested cons of Drill Down. I just explained and said you can sort but in different format for Drill Down too. And I have just gone with Drill Down and given more about Pivot Tables. Hope you understand and remove downvote. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest to keep it simple. If the objective is to present a view of the revenue figures of each region summarized by gender then pivot table in option 1 is the most effective of both, as it shows everything relevant in one simple look, keeping similar data at the same level making easier to compare.

Bear in mind that management requested that view to be able to effectively see how each region is performing on that specific category.

If the focus is revenue by different gender. Option 1 shows that in same row continuously for each region. It can easily be seen that the best performer on revenue generated by females is US, while best performer on revenue generated by males is Canada. While is not easy to see that in option 2.

If the focus is revenue by same gender. Option 1 shows that in same column continuously, which is not the case with option two.

Option 2 will be useful if the primary focus is set on revenue by region then if there is a need to see additional details based on the performance of any region management can drilldown to see the details of what makes the primary number. Which in this case is not the objective as the request is to show both.

Also best advice is to always agree requirements with clients (internal and/or external) you might find that they might have requested only what they believe it is possible to achieve and after they have that they will apply some "manual steps" to achieve their ultimate goal, something you could have done entirely if only you would have known.

Comment: Exactly on point w/r/t 'discuss with internal/external clients'. If you are in a position where Excel is your deliverable, then you should be crafting your deliverable in the way desired by those who will be using it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally every representation of data has a purpose and with this purpose there come certain advantages and disadvantages.
Obviously with any kind of report, the audience matters most. Which would put you in the classical Requirement Analysis situation where you need to figure out what your customer wants (What data is of interest? How should it be sliced? What medium is it consumed on?)

### Is the Revenue by Gender an important KPI?

If it is not, why including it at all?

If it is, let's see what a potential reader would do to answer a question like *"How does the womens sale for Mexico compare with Canada?"*

**Drill down table**:

1. Understanding the table will take a couple of second since they have to understand the different levels and their representation, the meaning of the bold and regular lines and realize that the man and women values accumulate to the total value for a region
2. Find Mexico in the list
3. Find the row for women and the value of it on the right
4. Find Canada in the list
5. Find the row for women and the value of it on the right
6. Remember the the value for Mexico or look it up again

Important here is also that this process will be repeated more or less exactly for every follow up question.

**Traditional table**

1. Understanding the table will be faster, they see a country name on the left and male/female on the top. Generally people are used to these tables since primary school and won't need further explanation.
2. Find Mexico in the list, go to the right until they find the value for women (if you try it you will see that you automatically see the values and the heading)
3. Find Canada in the list, (realize that it is only one line above) go to the right and have both values on top of each other.

For all the following questions the structure is easy to remember and it's a find and match game between rows and columns

*I know that might be a bit subjective, but I hope the general idea is understandable*

If you know have a question like *"In which region do we sell more to men than women?"* the advantage of a **traditional** over a **drill down** table becomes even more obvious.
With the drill down you will have to juggle several rows and their values while with the traditional you just skim through one column and look for the biggest value.

### Is the Revenue per Region the main KPI?

You should then rather use a **drill down** table, possibly with additional levels (ie. North America in case it's international data or US State since I would assume it would be of interest if your product sells better in Alaska than Florida).
Your audience can then decide which granularity they want to see and adjust it accordingly. The gender is on the bottom of the hierarchy so either you have curious people who are interested in just another figure or they don't care and just don't drill down that deep.
The assumption here is that you deliver the table on the highest aggregate level.

One could argue that the same problem of finding row etc. exists as well for this case but I would assume you wouldn't necessarily compare the sales for Yucatán with Alberta so you stay in one group of states for example and again just have to skim up or down to find the states of the same country so you can compare it.

Answer (score -1):

Using drilldowns in pivot tables is, in my opinion, a tool to be used by analysts, and not managers. Pivot tables are not quite intuitive enough to be used on reports that are being sent on for BI review by management. Typically any report which is being circulated for review by the powers that be should be consistent from user to user. That means using drilldowns would display different numbers if different items are selected - which could lead to 2 people talking about different values without knowing it.

Many people in management level positions outside of the core analytical group will still print anything you e-mail them before they look at it. I suspect that this is more likely to be true in a less technologically advanced company (ie: one which uses Excel as its database analysis tool instead of a full ERP-type system). In either case, anything being submitted for high level review should already be formatted exactly as you want them to see it.

The key in Excel deliverables within the workbplace is to make review as easy as possible. That means all necessary information should be immediately visible on each tab, with a minimum of scrolling (maybe scrolling down if necessary, but never scrolling right), and absolutely no clicking required.

**Conclusion - Do not force a reviewer to manipulate your Excel file to use it**

You may like drilldowns because you see how powerful it is to adjust reports as you are analyzing data - but once you have made your own analytical conclusions, those conclusions should be immediately apperent from the visible workspace that you leave for review.

Therefore, in order to achieve simplicity in high level review documents, you should use the 'traditional' format as you have shown it, which shows all numbers next to eachother in an easy to read table.